# Decrease Touch Area of UIButton

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I am trying to decrease the touch area of an UIButton. Is that even possible? When the user touches on the button and drags his touch outside the buttton the touch event should stop immediately when the graphic of the button ends. Unfortunately the area is much bigger than the actual graphic. I found a lot things on how to increase the area but not how to make it smaller.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you change the size of the button to match the size of graphics?

Comment: @barley I think what he is trying to say is, even though the button and graphic are the same size, when you click on the button and drag outwards the button doesn't depressed until you get a certain distance away. He wants it to depress right away.

Comment: @yuf Thanks for explanation. That sounds like an interesting challenge :)

Comment: I agree: the distance you have to drag off of a button to cancel it is way too huge. I keep dragging well off the button (at least 2x the height of the button itself) and it is *still* activating the button. It's infuriating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up one solution. You can subclass `UIButton` and override `touchesMoved:` so that it recognize the touch to be ended if it was outside of the button. Here is my snippet.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    if(!CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, touchPoint))
    {
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
    else
    {
        [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

The drawback of this is that if you go out of the button and come back again, the button will not become active. But otherwise, I think it should work fine.